# Apply curve_fit on dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with with multiple columns and I would like to apply a [`curve_fit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) function to each of them. I would like the output to be a dataframe with the optimal values fitting the data in the columns (for now, I am not interested in their covariance).

The df has the following structure:

```
    a  b  c
0   0  0  0
1   0  0  0
2   0  0  0
3   0  0  0
4   0  0  0
5   0  0  0
6   1  0  1
7   1  1  1
8   1  1  1
9   1  1  1
10  1  1  1
11  1  1  1
12  1  1  1
13  1  1  1
14  2  1  2
15  6  2  6
16  7  2  7
17  8  2  8
18  9  2  9
19  7  2  7
```

I have defined a function to fit to the data as so:

```
def sigmoid(x, a, x0, k):
     y = a / (1 + np.exp(-k*(x-x0)))
     return y
 
def fitdata(dataseries):
    popt, pcov=curve_fit(sigmoid, dataseries.index, dataseries)
    return popt
```

I can apply the function and get an array in return:

```
result_a=fitdata(df['a'])
In []: result_a
Out[]: array([  8.04197008,  14.48710063,   1.51668241])
```

If I try to `df.apply` the function I get the following error:

```
fittings=df.apply(fitdata)
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 3), indices imply (3, 20)
```

Ultimately I would like the output to look like:

```
           a          b          c
0   8.041970   2.366496   8.041970
1  14.487101  12.006009  14.487101
2   1.516682   0.282359   1.516682
```

Can this be done with something similar to [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope my solution work for you.

```
result = pd.DataFrame()
for i in df.columns:
    frames = [result, pd.DataFrame(fitdata(df[i]))]
    result = pd.concat(frames, axis=1)
result.columns = df.columns

           a           b           c
0   8.041970    2.366496    8.041970
1   14.487101   12.006009   14.487101
2   1.516682    0.282359    1.516682
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that the apply of your fitting function returns an array of dim 3x3 (the 3 fitparameters as returned by conner). But expected is something in the shape of 20x3 as your df.

So you have to re-apply your fitfunction on these parameters to get your fitted y-values.

```
def fitdata(dataseries):
    # fit the data
    fitParams, fitCovariances=curve_fit(sigmoid, dataseries.index, dataseries)
    # we have to re-apply a function to the coeffs. so that we get fittet 
    # data in shape of the df again.
    y_fit = sigmoid(dataseries, fitParams[0], fitParams[1], fitParams[2])
    return y_fit
```

Have a look [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/media.usm.maine.edu/~pauln/ScipyScriptRepo/CurveFitting.ipynb) for more examples

Answer (score 0):

(this post is based on both previous answers and provides a complete example including an improvement in the dataframe construction of the fit parameters)

The following function `fit_to_dataframe` fits an arbitrary function to each column in your data and returns the fit parameters (covariance ignored here) in a convenient format:

```
def fit_to_dataframe(df, function, parameter_names):
    popts = {}
    pcovs = {}

    for c in df.columns:
        popts[c], pcovs[c] = curve_fit(function, df.index, df[c])

    fit_parameters = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(popts,
                                            orient='index',
                                            columns=parameter_names)
    return fit_parameters

fit_parameters = fit_to_dataframe(df, sigmoid, parameter_names=['a', 'x0', 'k'])
```

The fit parameters are available in the following form:

```
          a         x0         k
a  8.869996  11.714575  0.844969
b  2.366496  12.006009  0.282359
c  8.041970  14.487101  1.516682
```

In order to inspect the fit result, you can use the following function to plot the results:

```
def plot_fit_results(df, function, fit_parameters):
    NUM_POINTS = 50
    t = np.linspace(df.index.values.min(), df.index.values.max(), NUM_POINTS)
    df.plot(style='.')
    for idx, column in enumerate(df.columns):
        plt.plot(t,
                 function(t, *fit_parameters.loc[column]),
                 color='C{}'.format(idx))
    plt.show()

plot_fit_results(df, sigmoid, fit_parameters)
```

Result: [Output Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYrxI.png)

This answer is also available as an interactive jupyter notebook [here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/kerel-fs/a623756fb0c70813889874b5367e9765).